# Failure to login via curl with a custom api in C++

Tags: c++, curl

I'm trying to create a login function via curl for my C++ application. Upon successful data being passed to the server, the server should return the response code 200. My information is the same as whats in the database aswell. I am using Visual Studio 2019 and C++ 17. I am also on Windows.

Note: The link I pass to the api is correct, I know it because I looked at Visual Studios debugger and the value was correct.

My code:

```
std::string API = "http://api.mywebsitenameishere.xyz/ovixau.php?username=" + username + "&password=" + password + "&hwid=TEST&authv=1";

CURL* curl = curl_easy_init();

if (!curl)
    printf("Curl failed to init.\n");
else
{
    int curl_code = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    long http_code = 0;
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, API.c_str());
    curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE, &http_code);
    if (http_code == 200 && curl_code != CURLE_ABORTED_BY_CALLBACK)
    {
        printf("Succesfully logged in!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Failed to log in, response code %ld", http_code);
    }
}
```

If there is something else I need to specify, feel free to ask. Thanks.

Comment: `curl_easy_setopt` should be called **before** `curl_easy_perform`. You are sending the request first, and only then setting the URL to which the request is supposed to be sent. Computers are not generally equipped with time machines.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thank you, I laughed at your comment lol. It works perfectly now, I cant believe I didnt see that before. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As Igor said, I was sending a request before I set the url of the api. I needed to switch curl_easy_setopt and curl_easy_perform. It works perfectly now, thank you Igor!